# C++ Error: 'no matching function for call to [class]::[function]'

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, reference

I have a template class `template <typename T> class MyClass` with a method:

```
void add (T& item) {
    data[indexToInsert++] = &item; // data is an array of T*
}
```

In main:

```
MyClass<int> thing;
thing.add(10);
```

On the second line, I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to MyClass::add(int)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Non-const lvalue references like `T&` can't bind to rvalues like `10`. How is the compiler supposed to take the address of `10`, anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your member function expects a reference to `T`, which would be `int&`. You are passing a plain `int`, not a variable of type `int`, of which C++ could take a reference. This is not allowed: you can pass an `int` in place of a constant reference, but not in place of a non-constant reference.

The reason for this is that when you pass a value in place of a constant reference, C++ can create a temporary object, copy the value into it, and pass a reference to that temporary to a function. Doing the same for a non-constant reference would be incorrect, because your code has no access to a potentially modifiable temporary object.

Your code illustrates the reason why this would be incorrect: you pass `10` to your function, but the function takes the address of the `item`. What is the address of `10`? C++ does not know, because integer literal `10` does not have an address.

You can fix the call by providing a variable of type `int`, setting it to `10`, and calling `add`:

```
MyClass<int> thing;
int ten = 10;
thing.add(ten);
```

However, you need to make sure that `thing` would not have a wider scope than `ten`, because otherwise you would end up with a "dangling pointer" inside the `data` array of the `thing` object.